# Why choose a Dirichlet distribution in Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA)?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I am studying Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA), but I don't have much knowledge of stochastic processes.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation):

> LDA assumes the following generative process for a corpus $D$
> consisting of $M$ documents each of length $N_{i}$:
>
> 1. Choose $\theta _{i}\sim \operatorname {Dir} (\alpha )$, where $i\in \{1,\dots ,M\}$ and $\mathrm {Dir} (\alpha )$ is a Dirichlet distribution with a symmetric parameter $\alpha$

My question is this: why Dirichlet distribution? Are there any particular properties of this distribution that make it suitable for this model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two properties that make the [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) a suitable default choice are:

1. **Flexibility:** it has full support on the parameter space which is the set possible values of the K-dimensional vector of probabilities, which must sum to 1 (i.e., the K-1 dimensional [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex))
2. **Computational tractability:** the Dirichlet distribution is the conjugate prior for the multinomial likelihood and can be analytically integrated out to obtain tractable marginal likelihood and Pólya urn schemes (see [Dirichlet multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet-multinomial_distribution)) this allows to have tractable algorithms to perform Bayesian inference (e.g., it gives tractable full conditional distribution in a Gibbs-sampler).

Point 2. is explained with more technical details in the Wikipedia page linked in your question in the Section **Aspects of computational details** or in the paper: [Blei, David M., Ng, Andrew Y. and Jordan, Michael I. "Latent Dirichlet Allocation". Journal of Machine Learning Research (2003)](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/blei03a/blei03a.pdf?ref=https://githubhelp.com)